# chrome extension insert content script on browser action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make basically an element highlighter chrome extension.
Workflow:
 - click on browser icon
 - click on the page
 - hightlight the element clicked

I am having troubles in running content scripts upon browser action using manifest_version:2
When I inspect the popup that appears it says:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   chrome-extension-resource:" (popup.html:5).

Which is where the inline script in popup.html is and the script does not work

I have:

manifest.json:

```
{
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "images/icon.gif",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "description": "MEH!",
   "name": "My First Extension",
   "permissions": [
      "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
   ],
   "version": "0.1"
}
```

popup.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{
        code:"document.body.style.backgroundColor='red'"
      });
    </script>
    <div id='msg' style="width:300px">...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Chrome extension popup is not working, click events are not handled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601615/the-chrome-extension-popup-is-not-working-click-events-are-not-handled)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Turns out I could not read the error properly until I saw it in here

Apparently manifest v2 does not allow you to have inline scripts, so you just need to

```
src="path_to_the_file.js"
```

Comment: For those who still don't get the answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17612988/938089

Comment: Where are you putting src? This answer is not clear.

Comment: inside the body. So instead of inserting a <script>console.log('a')</script> you would insert a script that points to a file, aka <script src="..."></script> inside the page's HTML (like inside the HEAD or what-not)

Answer (score 2):

In extension to @tak3r's answer and @Doug's comment:

Inline scripts need to be changed to external scripts.

Move:

```
<script>
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{
    code:"document.body.style.backgroundColor='red'"
  });
</script>
```

To a new file called `main.js` and remove the `<script></script>` tags

Include the following in the `<head></head>` of your HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```