# Click event not working in Chrome extension's Background page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I added a background page that contains a form with a button. I am using jQuery for handling DOM and events. On hitting **Search** button it doesn't work as expected, it should show **alert( "Handler for .click() called." );**

**Update**:  On Console I get:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   chrome-extension-resource:".

Relevant code given below:

**Manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name" : "my Ext,
    "description" : "Copy Rows",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches" : ["http://example.com/"],
        "js" : ["jquery.js","script.js"]
    }],
"background":{
  "scripts": ["jquery.js","background.js"]
},
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Title"
      }
}
```

**script.js**

```
var currentURL = document.location.href;
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });
});

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse)
{
    alert(msg.param);
    if (msg.method == "getHTML")
      sendResponse({data: "Welcome Bg"});
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
  var loaderURL = chrome.extension.getURL("dashboard.html");
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: loaderURL });
});

function search()
{
//    alert("hi search");
//    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {method: "getHTML",param:"myParam"}, function(response) {
//    alert(response.data);
//  });
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });

});
```

**dashboard.html** (My BackgroundPage)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form>
      <textarea id="serch"></textarea>
      <input id="button" type="button" value="Search" />
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545743/chrome-extension-insert-content-script-on-browser-action

Comment: @Dexter Yes I did figure it out too so I moved on code to background.js, I don't see the message but click is not working either.

Comment: Ok, I was not including **<script src="background.js"></script>**, when did it behaved as expected.
@Dexter can you please make your comment as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is solved here (essentially inline scripts were disallowed)

[chrome extension insert content script on browser action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545743/chrome-extension-insert-content-script-on-browser-action)